# Python zipfile module creates multiple files with same name

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have following code in python:

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> zip = zipfile.ZipFile('abc.zip', 'w')
>>> zip.writestr('myfile', 'This is sample text')
>>> zip.writestr('myfile', 'This is sample text')
>>> zip.close()
```

This creates an archive with two files having exactly same name and path.

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: How can you two files, with precisely the same name and path?

Comment: Looks like it creates two files with the same name and path in the archive when I try it, too. There's all the code necessary to reproduce it right in the question, so I don't understand the "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" close vote.

Comment: The zip format allows multiple files with the same name. Though I can't seem to find the appropriate documentation for that feature. If anyone finds a link, I would like to check that information.

Comment: This is an somewhat annoying feature of the archive formats. For example, Tar allows that as well, the file names are actually not used to identify the files. That's why you cannot rely on the file name when reading from a zip archive and should rather pass `ZipInfo`.

Comment: In a similar vein, what is defined as the 'same' is somewhat OS / filesystem specific. Eg. you can have 'file.json' and 'File.json' that end up colliding on OS X with case-insensitive filesystem. Don't get me started on things like 'file.aux' on Windows...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is allowed by Zip and some other archive formats, like Tar, and even addressed by the [Python API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.open):

> **Note:** The `open()`, `read()` and `extract()` methods can take a filename or a `ZipInfo` object. You will appreciate this when trying to read a ZIP file that contains members with duplicate names.